# What design tool shows zoomed-in and normal-size versions simultaneously?

Tags: icon, software-recommendation

Hopefully there is a way to do this in Sketch-- that is what I use :)

But does Illustrator or anything out there, natively or with a plugin, allow for a designer to simultaneously view a normal size and a zoomed-in version of an icon?  I find myself switching back and forth a hundred times.

Comment: Photoshop, Illustrator, Indesign and Fireworks all allow you to make multiple windows of a single document, where you can of course have different zoom level ( and/or view a different page in indesign ). They all also have navigator panel, which may help to some degree.

Comment: Joonas, that looks awfully like an answer to the question... :)

Comment: @AlanGilbertson  Technically the question doesn't ask directly about Sketch, but I feel that it's the most important part of the question, since OP is actually using it. I don't know about it, so I think my comment is just filler.

Answer (score 1):

Window → Arrange → New Window for *document-name* will do precisely what you’re after in Adobe Photoshop.

Window → New Window will do precisely what you’re after in Adobe Illustrator.

Many other Adobe apps can also spawn new windows of the same file. If you’re using Sketch, Sketch Mirror might do what you want, if you have an iPad handy.